# Using MediaMuxer instead of FileOutputStream to save frames into mp4 file

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer, android-video-record

I use next sample to record video from buffer (from `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data,...`). But it saves video using Output Stream. I would like to change to MediaMuxer.
Also when using this sample the final video is being played with very high speed in video player. I'm just not sure what time to set  for `encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, ptsUsec, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);` I use `long ptsUsec = (System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000) / FRAME_RATE;`

```
private void encodeVideoFrameFromBuffer(byte[] frameData) {
    if (encoder == null) return;
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000;
    ByteBuffer[] encoderInputBuffers = encoder.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

    if (!outputDone && outputStream == null) {
        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test" + 1280 + "x" + 720 + ".mp4";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            Log.d(TAG, "encoded output will be saved as " + fileName);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to create debug output file " + fileName);
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);

        }
    }
    if (outputStream != null) {
        int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);

        if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
            long ptsUsec = (System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000) / FRAME_RATE;
            if (outputDone) {
                encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, ptsUsec,
                        MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
            } else {
                ByteBuffer inputBuf = encoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];

                inputBuf.clear();
                inputBuf.put(frameData);
                encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, frameData.length, ptsUsec, 0);

            }
            generateIndex++;
        }


        int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
        if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            // no output available yet

        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            // not expected for an encoder
            encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
            Log.d(TAG, "encoder output buffers changed");
        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();
            Log.d(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + newFormat);
        } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
        } else { // encoderStatus >= 0
            ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
            encodedData.position(info.offset);
            encodedData.limit(info.offset + info.size);

            byte[] data = new byte[info.size];
            encodedData.get(data);
            encodedData.position(info.offset);
            try {
                outputStream.write(data);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.w(TAG, "failed writing debug data to file");
                throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
            }

            encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
        }
    }

    if (outputDone) {
        if (outputStream != null) {


            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.w(TAG, "failed closing debug file");
                throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
            }
            outputStream = null;
            stopEncoder();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    doEncodeDecodeVideoFromBuffer(data);

}
```

Comment: What is your codec? AVC?

Comment: @E.Abdel yes, h.264/avc

Comment: So your .mp4 is not realy a .mp4 file, it is a h264 file (you can play it with vlc right?)

Comment: @E.Abdel yes it's just a file output stream, that's why I asked this question, I would like to use `MediaCodec` with `MediaMuxer` to encode video (avc/h264) into mp4 container file

Answer (score 2):

About fast playing - try to use `System.nanoTime() / 1000L` instead of `(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000) / FRAME_RATE`

to use muxer you have to initialize it outside of your encode/decode process and feed it with sample data in decode part. Change your

```
try {
    outputStream.write(data);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    Log.w(TAG, "failed writing debug data to file");
    throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
}
```

to

```
//somewhere outside encode/decode part
MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
muxer = new MediaMuxer(/*your file*/,
                MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(encoder.getOutputFormat());
muxer.start();

//try-catch block replacement
muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, data, videoInfo);
```

don't forget to `stop()` and `release()` your muxer finally. That should work